# how to divide the string based on the # in android?

Tags: android, string, token, stringtokenizer

I have a string like "#123#456 #abc". my requirement is dividing the string into tokens based on the #.
So my result tokens are #123,#456,#abc.

How to divide the string in android?

Answer (score 1):

Just use string split method then add # to the start

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
   String str = "#123#456#abc";
   String[] arr = str.split("#");

    for(int i=1;i< arr.length;i++){
     System.out.println("#" + arr[i]);
    }
```

> Output

```
#123
#456
#abc
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split your `String` with regex `"#"`. I wrote an example for your case.

```
    final String entry = "#123#456#abc";
    String[] tokens = entry.split("#");
    // Your tokens array will contain {"", "123", "456", "abc"}

    // Filter out the empty values and add an '#' before the others
    List<String> formattedTokens = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String token : tokens) {
        if(token.length() > 0){
            formattedTokens.add(String.format("#%s", token));
        }
    }

    // Your formattedTokens list will contain {"#123", "#456", "#abc"}
```

Answer (score 0):

use String.split(#) for splitting the string into string[]
and then append # to each string after that

Answer (score 0):

see Rege for more info - you can set regular expression and parse String as you want